# Нужно сделать так, чтоб посты отображались один за одним, а не заменялись

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

Пишу сайт личных дневников, нужно сделать так, что посты отображались один за другим, а не заменялись при каждой отправки данных

```
<form method="post">
    <textarea name="myname" style="width:685px;height:375px;"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" style="width:90px;padding:5px;margin-left:600px;">
</form>
<?php 
  if ($POST['myname'] and $_POST['enter']) {
      $_POST['myname'] = FormChars($_POST['myname']);
      mysqli_query($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO `comen`  VALUES ('', '$_POST[myname]')");
  }
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "register_demo");
  $result_set = $mysqli->query('SELECT text FROM comen');
  while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()){
      echo $_POST['myname'];
      echo '</br>';
      echo '</br>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Делаю функцию добавления постов на сайте. У меня не получается, вместо добавления нового поста происходит замена старого поста новым.

Comment: если Вам помог ответ, отметьте его решением(галка слева от ответа под цифрой).

Answer (score 1):

Вы просто не выводите данные.
В цикле `while` Вы почему то выводите входные данные `$_POST['myname']`, вместо того, чтобы вывести информацию из базы данных.
Плюс у Вас ошибка в запросе бд и присвоении значения `$_POST['myname']`.

Исправьте Ваш код на следующий:

```
<form method="post">
    <textarea name="myname" style="width:685px;height:375px;"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" style="width:90px;padding:5px;margin-left:600px;">
</form>
<?php 
  if ($POST['myname'] and $_POST['enter']) {
      $myname = FormChars($_POST['myname']);
      mysqli_query($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO `comen`  VALUES ('', '$myname')");
  }
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "register_demo");
  $result_set = $mysqli->query('SELECT text FROM comen');
  while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()){
      echo $row["text"];
      echo '</br>';
      echo '</br>';
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

По идее у Вашей таблицы должны быть айдишники с автоинкрементом. Чтобы последние записи отображались сверху, нужно их соответственно отсортировать.
Например так:

```sql
SELECT text FROM comen ORDER BY id DESC
```